# set action (gesture recognizer) on text which is inside of textView

Tags: ios, swift2, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, nsattributedstring

okay so assume the below text as it is inside an textView

```
bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla     *doAction*
```

i have some text which i'm showing in my textView and i want to trigger an action when some desired text is tapped by user in the above example i want to trigger and action when user taps on ***doAction***. i dont know how i'm gonna do this and even if this is possible or not i know how can i put a link on my textView but this is not the same case here. anybody can guide me how i'm gonna achieve this ??

p.s. if question is not clear enough then let me know i'll fix it.

Answer (score 3):

1) Using `attributedString`, you can achieve the desired behaviour. Below is example:-

```
  @IBOutlet weak var terms: UITextView!

  let privacyURL = "http://www.programmincrew.in";

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.terms.delegate = self
    let str = "By using this app you agree to our Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy"
       let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
    let foundRange = attributedString.mutableString.rangeOfString("Privacy Policy")
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: privacyURL, range: foundRange)
    terms.attributedText = attributedString
  }



    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
 if (URL.absoluteString == privacyURL) {
          let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Conditions", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
          myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
          self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        return false
      }
```

2) Set the `dataDetectorTypes` property pf the UITextView to `UIDataDetectorTypeLink`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to add a gesture recognizer to get the tap point in your textview.
**UITextView** subclass that executes a block when a user taps a specified word or phrase.

Try this demo :-

**Objective C** [HBVLinkedTextView](https://github.com/evilBird/HBVLinkedTextView)

**Swift** [SwiftTextViewHashtag](https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/SwiftTextViewHashtag)

Comment: well this is exactly what i'm looking for but there's only one thing its on ObjC. i'll try to convert it since i'm not a ObjC person , still thanks a lot

Comment: @remyboys Why need to convert it? You can just add it into your project and use it in swift normally

Comment: so that i can see what is actually going on there @Tj3n